# Python Web-Scraping Table

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from a website using pythin.  The website contains a lot of different workouts that each have their own data.  I have figured out how to scrape the data from each specific workout, however to do that I must provide a specific workout id in the url.  The home page appears to list all these workout ids in a table, however when I search the html document using 
beautiful soup the following table data is returned:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th ng-click="order('class_name')" style="cursor:pointer;">Name</th>
<th ng-click="order('location')" style="cursor:pointer;">Location</th>
<th ng-click="order('trainer')" style="cursor:pointer;">Instructor</th>
<th ng-click="order('class_date_sec')" style="cursor:pointer;">Date</th>
<th ng-click="order('points')" style="cursor:pointer;">OT Points</th>
<th ng-click="order('CALORIES')" style="cursor:pointer;">Total Calories 
(kCal)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="otf-class-body">
<tr calories="{{class.CALORIES | number:0}}" class_date="{{class.class_date}} 
    at {{class.class_time}}" class_name="{{class.class_name}}" date_order=" 
    {{class.date_order}}" id="{{class.CLASSID}}" loc="{{class.loc}}" 
    location=" {{class.location}}" ng-click="view(class.CLASSID, 
    class.at_home)" ng-repeat="class in classes | orderBy:predicate:reverse" 
    points=" {{class.points | number:0}}" trainer="{{class.trainer}}">
<td>{{class.class_name}}</td>
<td>{{class.location}}</td>
<td>{{class.trainer}}</td>
<td>{{class.class_date}} at {{class.class_time}}</td>
<td>{{class.points | number:0}}</td>
<td>{{class.CALORIES | number:0}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see there is no actual text, instead all the information seems a variable of some sort (my html knowledge is extremely limited).  It appears the information I want would be a list of all:

```
class.CLASSID
```

Is it possible to use python to obtain this information?  Or it using some api that I do not have access to.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a django page, provide me the website url please, and are you using  urllib or webdriver?

Comment: The website address is https://carmel.orangetheoryfitness.com/apps/otf/classes however it is behind a login page so I am not certain you will be able to view it.  I have provided a copy of the html at a pastebin. https://pastebin.com/BnvdZmSp.  I am currently using beautifulsoup to search the html.  Do I need to be using something else?

Comment: bs4 is awesome but what are you using for the requests? are you using urllib or selenium?

Comment: I am using requests.    
import requests.       s = requests.session()

Comment: with requests it wont work man requests is http library it cant run javascript try with selenium and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

Ok mate :) i think this is going to work but with python3.x 
hope it helps

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options =webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
# If you want it headless uncomment the line underneath and comment  out driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = ('https://carmel.orangetheoryfitness.com/login')
driver.get(url)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
inputElement.send_keys("YOUR EMAIL HERE")#put your email between the ""s
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
inputElement.send_keys("YOUR PASSWORD HERE")#put your password between the ""s
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.get("carmel.orangetheoryfitness.com/apps/otf/classes")
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```

## recap

since it wants you to be logged in, the solution, that i know,
is with selenium.
For sure there are other methods out there and i hope that the folks will share :) 
i advice you to use it headless because its less messier the browser will run in the background but for debug use it like that,
once you are ready with the code just uncomment the headless and everything will work like a charm I hope that I helped you mate! cheers for any questions feel free to ask

## Code on!